# Creating an admin only view portion | Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have developed a fairly simple blog platform (based on rails 5 and ruby 2.3.2) that only allows users of admin status to edit, update, delete, and create new blog posts. There are two models
1. Blogpost.rb (belongs_to user)
2. User.rb     (has_many blogposts)

I am trying to only allow admin users to view the edit/delete buttons in my 'blogpost/show' view, but as of now my admin_user before filter doesn't appear to take effect. IE: When a non admin user clicks edit, or (if I try to implement current_user.admin?) it throws a 'no method error for admin?'

I have tried implement a 'non_logged_user' to change my if/else commands in my views with no success. My code is below:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">

<h1><%= @blogpost.title %></h1>
<p><%= @blogpost.content %></p>
<% if current_user.admin? %>
<%= link_to "Edit Post", edit_blogpost_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %> | 
<%= link_to "Delete Post", blogpost_path(@blogpost), 
                        method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
<% end %>
```

**blogposts_controller**

```
class BlogpostsController < ApplicationController
include SessionsHelper
before_action :admin_user, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :non_logged_user, only: [:show]

def new
    @blogpost = current_user.blogposts.build
end

def create
    @blogpost = admin_user.blogposts.build(blogpost_params)
    if @blogpost.save
        flash[:success] = 'Post successfully created!'
        redirect_to blogpost_path(@blogpost)
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Post failed to be created!'
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @blogpost = Blogpost.find(params[:id])
end


def update
    @blogpost = Blogpost.find(params[:id])
    @blogpost.update(blogpost_params)
    if @blogpost.save
        flash[:success] = "#{@blogpost.title} has been updated!"
        redirect_to blogposts_path(@blogpost)
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = "#{@blogpost.title} was unable to be updated!"
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def index
    @blogposts = Blogpost.paginate( page: params[:page], :per_page => 10 )
end

def show
    @blogpost = Blogpost.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @blogpost = Blogpost.find(params[:id])
    if @blogpost.destroy
        redirect_to blogposts_path
        flash[:success] = "Post successfully destroyed"
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = "You are unable to remove this post"
        redirect_to blogposts_path
    end
end


    private

    def blogpost_params
        params.require(:blogpost).permit( :title, :content )
    end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

**application_controller** (includes SessionHelper) which defines logged in users + cookies)

```
private

######BEFORE_FILTERS######

def logged_in_user
  unless logged_in?
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end

def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

end

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :blogposts, dependent: :destroy
attr_accessor :remember_token #see method below (creates a virtual token not stored in db)
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password #enables bcrypt
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true


  def User.digest(string) #obtained from Bcrypt | returns the digest of a given password or (string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
end

def User.new_token #generates random token 
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def remember #remembers new token of said user when "remember" is activated by user
  self.remember_token = User.new_token #generates SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 of the virtual token (User.new_token)
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token)) #bypasses validations via update_attribute, updating 
                                                                  #the remember_digest and encrypting with User.digest method
end

def authenticated?(remember_token) #Bcrypt checks for matching remember digest and remember token (is_password? supplied by bcypt)
return false if remember_digest.nil?
BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
```

end

# Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
end

```
    module SessionsHelper

  def log_in(user) #logs said user in
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id) #deletes session
    @current_user = nil #set previous session user to nil 
  end

  # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def current_user #determines if user is logged out or is the current user of the session/cookie of profile
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end
```

Comment: Have you defined `admin?` in your User model?

Comment: As mmichael says, can you post your User model?  Do you have an `admin?` method defined there?

Comment: Is it required if my User model has an Admin:boolean column?

Comment: @ColtonVanBastelaere Is it _required_? No. But if you don't want to add a method for `admin?`, then yes, it's required. Thanks to [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), adding that boolean `admin` column will give you access to `admin?`.

Comment: @mmichael I already have it set as a boolean column inside my User Model.

Comment: @ColtonVanBastelaere Could you please post the exact error you're getting for that `admin?` method call?

Comment: @mmichael 'undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: @ColtonVanBastelaere Aaaand there it is. The issue isn't with the `admin?` method but because `current_user` is `nil`. Since it doesn't look like you're using `Devise`, how are you defining `current_user`? And if it's defined, debug into the code that triggers the error and inspect the user object.

Comment: So I added the sessions_helper.rb file I have made, and am now just realizing that me using my current_user method isn't doing what I need it to do, it's only pertaining to logging in a user, and ensuring it has done so correctly. How should I best implement a new method like what I am searching for?

Comment: A shortcut solution would be to replace instances of `current_user.admin?` with `current_user.try(:admin?)`. Otherwise, I'd create a class or instance method in your User model that checks whether or not the "current" user is an admin.

Comment: Ah perfect tyvm. Didn't know about 'try' I will define a method but try in this case is a cool method to know about! I would also like to note that if I ever do this again, itll be with devise! I am only doing this because I am a beginner who is writing his own code with a mix code from lots of documentation! Gotta learn somehow, and I'm all on my own where I live!